# Permanently mount virtual disk on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019.  I want to mount a virtual hard drive in Disk Manager and have it stay mounted across reboots.  I created the .vhd image in Disk Manager and mounted it and used it and all was well.  However after I rebooted the server it was no longer mounted.

Is there a way to automatically attach and mount a virtual disk in Windows?  I didn't see any setting like that in Disk Manager or in the drive's property sheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From a functional standpoint, the solution was to create a small physcial partition to house directory symbolic links to the server locations.

```
C:\>mklink /?
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

```
X:\>mklink /d X:\virtual_dir \\server_name\share\application_directory
```

Comment: I hate to say, this is NOT AN ANSWER. See, it solves the problem of ACCESSING the files, but it is NOT doing it in a way that is identical with what you describe. As such, it is not a solution to the question as asked.

Comment: Windows does not have a way to permanently mount a virtual drive or disk.  Creating a small physical partition to house the symlinks is all there is and it does solve the functional requirement.

Comment: Nope. As the other answer indicates a script can be used to mount the partition on every boot. As such, this answer is wrong. Not, it may be a case of not writing the question properly, but that is not my problem. As written this is not an answer, but the other answer is, triggering a mount on every startup.

Comment: I like how you think you know my own question better than me.  #1 is not a suitable answer for my purpose.  It is not a built in way to mount a drive.  It hides the configuration.  It probably won't execute in safe mode.  It's subject to race conditions.  Using a VHD in the first place was just a means to the functional requirement.  Don't be That Guy.

Comment: Nope, I just bother to READ your question. Not interpret what you have not written. Your purpose does not matter - what matters is that the answer fits the question. if you have written the question wrong, this does mean other people get sidetracked.

Comment: Ergo, "From a functional standpoint".... in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with Task Scheduler:

1. Create a new  task with trigger “*At Startup*”
2. Add action “*Start Program*” with program name `powershell.exe` and arguments `Mount-VHD -Path “\\server_name\folder\file.vhd”`
3. In general tab of task check the boxes “*Run with highest privileges*” and “*Run whether user is logged on or not*”
4. In general tab of task select the user, which is local admin and has read/write access to vhd file.